# How to self initialize a class in wp plugin development?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, init

Below is a sample code for a WP plugin. I want to include a styleheet with a function in the class. But my 'init' hook won't run init function.

```
class RentProduct{

public function init() {

    load_plugin_textdomain( 'eg', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang' );

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_plugin_styles' ) );

    // add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'append_post_notification' ) );
}


public function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'style', plugins_url( 'eg/assets/css/style.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
}
}

add_action( 'init', array( 'RentProduct', 'init' ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had my debug mode on earlier.. I could at earliest see error that `$this is undefined`. I was suppose to use class name instead of $this. Reason I cannot use $this is class is yet to be initialized and $this is instance of class. So $this would work fine in other methods of class coz initialization is already done at that time.

```
class RentProduct{

public static function init() {

    // load_plugin_textdomain( 'lang', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang' );

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( 'RentProduct' , 'register_plugin_styles' ) );

    // add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'append_post_notification' ) );
}


public static function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'main', plugins_url( 'wc-rent-products/assets/css/main.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main' );
}
}

add_action( 'init', array( 'RentProduct', 'init' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create new instance from your class
$rentProduct = new RentProduct();

class RentProduct {
    // __construct will be called, if you call the class
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_plugin_styles' ) );
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'eg', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang' );
    }


    public function register_plugin_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'style', plugins_url( 'eg/assets/css/style.css' ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
    }
}
```

Comment: With self initialization.. I meant without creating instance. Anyways..thanks..I figured it out by myself.